# Querying ManyToMany Relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

Suppose I have the following models, where Questions and Choices have a many-to-many relationship, and Choices and Voters have a many-to-many relationship. (To understand it better, consider a poll where each Question can have multiple Choices and each Choice can be associated to multiple Questions, and where each Choice stores a list of people who Voted for it, and Voters could have voted for multiple Choices.)

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField('Choice')

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField('Voter')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Voter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='FNU')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Given a Question object `ques1`, I want to be able to get a list of all Voters associated to the Choices for that question, i.e. I want a QuerySet of all Voters who voted for one or more of the Choices associated to the Question object `ques1`.

Therefore if Choices `c1` and `c2` are associated to Question `ques1`, and Voters `v1` and `v2` voted for Choice `c1` and Voter `v3` voted for Choice `c2`, then running the query on Question `ques1`, I would want a QuerySet containing `[v1, v2, v3]`.

**Is there any query for this?**

The highly-inefficient workaround of course is to iterate through `ques1.choices`, and update a running list of all voters with each iteration. I guess it could be made slightly more efficient by using `select_related`, but not a spot on having a clean query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do:

```
Voter.objects.filter(choice__in=ques1.choices.all()).distinct()    # Used distinct() to get unique voters.
```

Read more about it in [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: That's what I was missing! Didn't strike me to go at it the other way. Thanks :D